# Как спарсить один элемент с сайта?

Tags: python, requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

main_url = 'https://wynncraft.com/'
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}


req = requests.get(main_url, headers)

src = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

vacancies_names = soup.find_all('h2', class_='uB main-text equalizer')
for name in vacancies_names:
    print(name.a['title'])
```

Не понимаю как спарсить всего один элемент с сайта(извините за столь глупый вопрос).
[image: Нужно спарсить счетчик онлайна с сайта]

Нужно спарсить счетчик онлайна с сайта. В интернете инфы как спарсить похожий элемент не нашел

Comment: жабаскрипт отключите, и наверняка этот ваш «счётчик» пропадёт. значит, он создаётся динамически. значит, можете смело выкидывать в мусорку эти ваши requests-ы/beautifulsoap-ы - они интерпретатор жабаскрипта не эмулируют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import json

a=requests.get('https://api.wynncraft.com/v3/player')
res=json.loads(a.text)
print(res['total'])
print(res['players'])
```

---

```
997
{'563e': 'WC4', , ...  , 'Cliffer_': 'WC25', 'alontavor2011': 'WC22'}
```